# How to determine there are no running jobs or consumer process exit

Tags: data-structures, redis

In our business scenarios, we have a job queue, one producer process and several consumer processes.The producer only put new jobs into the queue when all consumers has no job running. The consumer may die or stuck. If that consumer not working any more, the producer should consider this dead consumer has finished its job.

We use redis server as our job queue. How to design the redis data structure to make this process efficiently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No one answer my question, but I came up a solution on my own.

**step 1**. Before the producer starting to put jobs into the queue,  I set a flag key: `SET dispatch.finished 0`.

**step 2**. After the producer finished putting all jobs into the queu, change the flag: `SET dispatch.finished 1`

**step 3**. Keep a set of worker ids: "SADD workers ID1 ID2"

**step 4**. When the worker fetched some jobs to execute, it set a flag: `SET worker.ID1.busy 1`, and add expire to this flag: `EXPIRE worker.ID1.busy 3`

**step 5**. When the worker found there are no jobs in queue, and  `dispatch.finished == 1`, then it update its busy flag: `SET worker.ID1.busy 0`

**step 6**. Next circle, the producer need to check all workers busy flag are zero(or not exists), and the jobs queue is empty,  then it continue step 1.